# Hexo cannot connect to github

Tags: ssh, connection, hexo

When trying to use hexo to submit blog content, many warnings suddenly occurred, and at the end it prompted that it could not connect to github.

```
warning: in the working copy of 'atom.xml', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'css/hbe.style.css', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'css/main.css', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'css/noscript.css', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'js/FunnyTitle.js', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'js/bookmark.js', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'js/clicklove.js', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'js/comments-buttons.js', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'js/comments.js', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'js/config.js', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'js/crypto-js.js', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'js/dytitle.js', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'js/excanvas.js', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/zuquanzhi/myname.github.io.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443 after 21102 ms: Couldn't connect to server
FATAL Something's wrong. Maybe you can find the solution here: https://hexo.io/docs/troubleshooting.html
Error: Spawn failed
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (D:\blog\myblog\node_modules\hexo-util\lib\spawn.js:51:21)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:517:28)
    at cp.emit (D:\blog\myblog\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:292:12)
```

Network Connection Stability:

I began by verifying the stability of my internet connection to ensure that it remained active and robust.
GitHub SSH Key Configuration:

I checked and confirmed the accurate configuration of my GitHub SSH keys. I considered generating new SSH keys and incorporating them into my GitHub account for enhanced security.
I used the ssh -vT git@github.com command to assess SSH connection verbosity, providing intricate details regarding connection attempts.
Firewall and Antivirus Checks:

I investigated whether my firewall or antivirus software could be impeding the connection. Temporarily disabling these applications helped me discern if they contributed to the issue.
Hexo Configuration Assessment:

I scrutinized my Hexo _config.yml file to guarantee precise configuration, including the correct repository URL and SSH URL since I was using SSH.
GitHub Repository Settings Review:

I confirmed that my GitHub repository settings permitted SSH connections and validated that my SSH key was successfully associated with my GitHub account.
Hexo Version and Dependencies Inspection:

I ensured compatibility by confirming that I was using a Hexo version that aligned with my system requirements and that all dependencies were updated.
GitHub Status Verification:

I visited the GitHub Status page (https://www.githubstatus.com/) to ascertain whether any ongoing issues were affecting GitHub services.
Error Messages Examination:

I paid close attention to specific error messages or warnings encountered during the process, as this information was pivotal for targeted issue resolution.
Hexo Plugins Evaluation:

If deployment involved Hexo plugins, I scrutinized their configurations to ensure accuracy and compatibility with my Hexo version.
Git Configuration Review:

I examined my Git configuration to ensure correctness, encompassing details such as my configured name and email.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an SSH problem: you told that system to connect to GitHub using HTTPS (evidence is in the error, which mentions `https://github.com/zuquanzhi/myname.github.io.git` and not `git@github.com:zuquanzhi/myname.github.io.git` or `ssh://git@github.com/zuquanzhi/myname.github.io.git`). For whatever reason (most likely a firewall or proxy issue), that HTTPS request is timing out.

(Also: the `user.name` and `user.email` parameters in your Git config have *nothing* to do with authentication. They are *only* there to indicate the author of a commit. Changing those will not affect how you connect to GitHub or any other service.)

You can change the remote URL in that repository with `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:zuquanzhi/myname.github.io.git` - that will update the `origin` remote to use SSH for that GitHub repository.